# Dynamic array from an input file

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic-arrays

I'm a beginner, so I'm sorry if this is really dumb question/problem. 
The assignment that I have is printing out a dynamic array from an input file. I tried googling it and I found some similar problems... but the answers were all like "use vectors" etc but we haven't learned those yet. It's also said that a function must be used. This is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //file input

using namespace std;

int *out(int *arr, int siz){

    arr = new int[siz];
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
        cout << arr [i] << " ";
    }
    return arr; //this should print out the array later???

}

int main(){

    int siz;
    int *arr;

    ifstream inf ("input.txt");
    inf >> siz; //
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
        inf >> arr[i];
    }
    inf.close();


    cout << "This array contains following elements: ";
    *arr = *out(arr, siz) ; 

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;}
```

So, it doesn't give any errors with Dev-C++ but when I try to run it, it crashes. I tried debugging it and then it gave me "segmentation error" or something like that. Then of course, I googled it and there must be something wrong with the pointers, right? Could you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Use a more recent and C++11 standard conforming compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), and compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Then use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Other than that, your parts of your code make no sense (The thing with the return value...)

Comment: You are reading your file to an unalloacated memory 'arr'. First allocate your memory and then read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access arr, when arr has not been allocated or initialized to a valid array. Your main needs to allocate arr before using arr to populate elements:
So, here's the changed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //file input

using namespace std;

void out(int *arr, int siz){
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
        cout << arr [i] << " ";
    }
}

int main(){

    int siz;
    int *arr;

    ifstream inf ("input.txt");
    inf >> siz; 
    arr = new int[siz]; // added
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
        inf >> arr[i];
    }
    inf.close();

    cout << "This array contains following elements: ";
    out(arr, siz); 

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is an **uninitialized** pointer.
Do `arr = new int[size];` before you read data into `arr`.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why I thought that. I'm having a look around to see what could have lead me to believe that.

Comment: It's a fair concern, just wasn't a valid argument in this case. C does not allow non-const integrals for array size during declaration.

Comment: THAT'S IT. I was trying to remember which language it was.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated memory to the array, which you'd likely need to do with `malloc`. Once you've read in the size of the array, allocate the memory.

```
inf >> siz;
arr = malloc(siz * sizeof(*int));
//Rest of program

//delete[] arr; <- you use this with the new keyword
free(arr); //Use 'free' with malloc
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want might be sth like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(){
    int siz(0);
    std::ifstream inf ("input.txt");//Assume that the input file and this file are in the same folder
    inf >> siz; //Assume that the first number in  input file is the size of array
    int *arr=new int[siz];
    for (int i = 0; (siz-i)&&inf ; ++i) {
        inf >> arr[i];
    }
    inf.close();

    std::cout << "This array contains following elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; siz -i ; ++i ) {
        std::cout << arr [i] << " ";
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```